# DRY creation of multiple Querysets

Tags: django, filter, dry, django-queryset

I am starting to use Django and while I have read the book and googled away I am afraid that I am not making the connection on some concepts to be able to resolve this.

I need to show several values corresponding to particular companies. The user first selects three companies to compare and then the response shows the data for those companies.

In my view, I create the querysets that I iterate in my template to show the data as follows:

VIEWS EXCERPT:

```
        C1 = form.cleaned_data['Company1']
        C2 = form.cleaned_data['Company2']
        C3 = form.cleaned_data['Company3']

        company_names = [C1,C2,C3]

        company1 = (Company_stats.objects.filter(period__exact=P, company_name__exact=C1))
        company2 = (Company_stats.objects.filter(period__exact=P, company_name__exact=C2))
        company3 = (Company_stats.objects.filter(period__exact=P, company_name__exact=C3))

        company_list = [company1,company2,company3]
```

TEMPLATE EXCERPT:

```
  {%for c in company_list%}    
     {%for z in c %}
        {{ z.company_name }}
        {{ z.nxt_m_ret_est }}    
        {{ z.nxt_m_ret_rat }}
     {% endfor %}  
  {% endfor %}
```

This works - however, as I have many more moving parts (I have simplified the view for the purpose of my question) it turns into an endless laundry list of querysets - I am 100% sure this is not DRY (in spite of the laundry reference ;) Not to mention the length of the context.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me learn to do this in the proper way. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
companies = ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3']

company_names = [form.cleaned_data[c] for c in companies]

company_list = Company_stats.objects.filter(
    period__exact=P, 
    company_name__in=company_names
)
```

Even if this doesn't exactly fit your need, something similar should work.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your help :) and for responding so quickly. I am sorry it took me a bit to test - I had to recreate this in my entangled view!

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that cookie-cutter queries are where [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) really shine.  Definitely consider using them if you find you need to make that same query elsewhere in your code too.  I avoided them for a while out because I perceived them to be complex, but they're really not so bad and they can clean up your code quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you, acjohnson55! I will definitely take a look at Managers.